# Вызов функции из DLL из командной строки

Tags: c++, dll

у меня есть функция в DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void test(char *text, len);
```

Как правильно её вызвать из командной строки? Пока пытаюсь делать так:

```
rundll32 mydll.dll,test "string" 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте [описание как использовать `rundll32`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787). Вкратце - не любая ф-ция может быть вызвана из библиотеки, а строго следующая определенным соглашениям, описанным в статье по ссылке.

Если по-простому и по-русски, то `rundll32` поддерживает только ф-ции со следующей сигнатурой:

```
void CALLBACK
   EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

Обратите внимание на аргументы и на то, что ф-ция должна следовать соглашению `_stdcall`, а не `_cdecl`.

Comment: Такая запись возможна ? 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void CALLBACK test(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow); По другому просто не видит експорта функции..

Comment: по идее этого будет достаточно.

1. `extern "C"` говорит компилятор, чтобы он не портил название ф-ции;
2. `__declspec(dllexport)` помещает ф-цию в таблицу экспорта DLL;
3. `CALLBACK` на самом деле скрывает в себе, что это `_stdcall`, т.е. порядок разбора и передачи аргументов ф-ции.